# Realm app working on the simulator but not on an actual device

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

When I run the Realm demo app ([link](https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/example-app/cocoa/)) on the XCode simulator it works as expected. I get the following error when I try run it on my tethered device (the screen is unlocked):

```
fatal error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1740467b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}): file /Users/grant/Apps/RealmTasksTutorial/RealmTasksTutorial/ViewController.swift, line 47
2016-10-28 11:16:59.148862 RealmTasksTutorial[1930:429715] fatal error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1740467b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}): file /Users/grant/Apps/RealmTasksTutorial/RealmTasksTutorial/ViewController.swift, line 47
(lldb)
```

Is Realm meant to work on an actual device when developing or only the simulator?

Comment: You're getting a Server error connection, check the IP address. From your code I'm getting you're trying to connect to the IP 127.0.0.1. It may work on your simulator. When running on the device, the localhost, equivalent to the 127.0.0.1 is the device itself. You have no servers running in the device. That's why you're not getting a response.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I would have to setup a deployed realm server to test on a device?

Comment: That's right, you should deploy your server and change the IP pointing to it.

Comment: Thanks! Working on that now.

Answer (score 2):

What Orlando has said is correct. When running a local instance of Realm Object Server on your Mac, you just need to set the IP address in your demo app to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. But when deploying to an actual device, you'll need to supply the IP address of the Mac on the local network in order for the device to connect to it. You can find this easily by holding down 'Alt' and clicking on the WiFi icon in the system bar of your Mac.

Manually changing the IP address between Simulator and device builds is tedious, so if you'd like check out how we did it in the [Realm Tasks demo app](https://github.com/realm/RealmTasks).

Upon building the app, a script is run (In the 'Build Phases' of the project) that will grab the Mac's IP address and then write it to a Swift file as a `String` variable. That variable is then used in the Realm code when it detects it's not being built for the Simulator.

Comment: This fixed it for me, just note... you need to update both these lines with your Mac's IP addree to connect your device properly...SyncUser.logIn(with: .... and syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(...

Comment: @TiM nice! Thx.